# What's the type of returned props in Next.js/TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

Currently tyring to practice Next.js and running into some very rookie issues, would love some clarification, to get that 'ahaa' moment.

I'm using Next.js and learning Sanity, trying to fetch data (following the Sanity tutorial actually). However, the returned props that I want to use in my component are `undefined` for some reason? And I don't know why, I'd like to know why.

Based on the below code, I'd like to know two things:

1. How can I *'know'* what the type is of returned props?
2. If I know 1, I probably know 2 too? But, why are my props `undefined`?

```js
export const fetchData = async () => {
  const pets = await client.fetch(`*[_type == "pet"]`);

  return {
    props: {
      pets,
    },
  };
};
```

Thanks to anyone who helps me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export const fetchData = async () : Promise<Pet[]> => {
  return await client.fetch(`*[_type == "pet"]`);
};
```

you can either generate types with [sanity-codegen](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/sanity-codegen) or you can write manually and annotate the function as above.